# Upload raw JSON data on Google Cloud Storage using Python code

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload raw JSON data on Google Cloud Platform. But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not dict
```

Code:

```
def upload_data(destination_path):
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    content = {'name': 'test'}
    media = http.MediaIoBaseUpload(StringIO(content), mimetype='plain/text')
    req = service.objects().insert(
        bucket=settings.GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        body={"cacheControl": "public,max-age=31536000"},
        media_body=media,
        predefinedAcl='publicRead',
        name=destination_path,
    )
    resp = req.execute()

    return resp
```

Code Worked by changing `StringIO(content)` to `StringIO(json.dumps(content))`

Comment: Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Could you add more information to what imports you've used to get this to work?

Comment: so i've found out by doing some digging. To get this to work you'll need -----

`from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient import http
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import io`

for predefinedAcl options you can go here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#predefined-acl

bucket needs to be the full name of your bucket. If you come from firebase it's "<name>.appspot.com"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your example, `content` is a dict.  Perhaps you want to use json?

```
content = json.dumps({'name': 'test'})
```

Comment: It Worked. missed this simple thing. was trying number of different things for this. Thanks. :)

Comment: This above code is working absolutely fine in python manage.py shell . But not in local server. Can you suggest any possible reasons for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own comment question on how to get this to work:

To get this to work you'll need

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient import http
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import io
```

Also i needed to change this:

```
 media = http.MediaIoBaseUpload(StringIO(content), mimetype='plain/text')
```

in to this:

```
media = http.MediaIoBaseUpload(io.StringIO(json.dumps(content)), mimetype='plain/text')
```

Note the insert of 'io' besides the json.dumps recommended by Corey Goldberg.

for **predefinedAcl** options you can go here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#predefined-acl

Bucket needs to be the full name of your bucket. If you come from firebase it's "[name].appspot.com"